# Compact pointers to retrieve array element

Tags: c

I would like to access a 2-dimensional array using a compact notation.

If the array is defined as a pointer array as below, then how I can parse through array elements?

```
int main(void)
{
    char *a[2] = {
    "databytes",
    "dataword"
    };
    
    char **q = a;

    return 0;
}
```

The following approach works very well.

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[2][10] = {
    "databytes",
    "dataword"
    };
    //char **p = a;
    char *q = &a[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%c\n", *q++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You probably aren't seeing the `'\0'` value elements (all the elements that were not explicitly initialised) as characters in your terminal. In mine, I get a blank line for each, but they aren't *part of the actual data*.

Comment: You can treat a contiguous memory area as if it is an array of a variable number of pointers to variables sized strings (the usual convention is to use two `NUL` bytes after the last string). In this case, the space you allocated to each string is known to you. But, by the time you get to `q`, that knowledge has been lost. See also http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Comment: What is a "compact notation"? `then how I can parse through array elements?` Normally, like with an 2d array, `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) print("%c", a[i][j]);`

Comment: "The following approach works very well". It is undefined behaviour, as clearly stated in appendix J2 of the standard: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int a[4][5]`)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should help illustrate the layout of `a` for you. `a` correspond to a storage read of 2 × 10 = 20 bytes. If `a[0]` points to a string consisting of 9 characters, those and the `NUL` take up space set aside for that string. On the other hand, if `a[1]` points to a string consisting of 5 characters, it takes up a total of 6 bytes of storage and the values at `a[1][6]` through `a[1][9]` are uninitialized. Therefore, once you reach the end of a string, you need to skip to the beginning of the next one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char a[][10] = {
        "databytes",
        "hello",
        "dataword",
    };

    char* q = &a[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0, offset = i * sizeof(a[0]);
             *(q + offset) && (j < sizeof(a[0]));
             ++j, ++offset) {
            printf("%c --- (%d)\n", *(q + offset), j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
d --- (0)
a --- (1)
t --- (2)
a --- (3)
b --- (4)
y --- (5)
t --- (6)
e --- (7)
s --- (8)
h --- (0)
e --- (1)
l --- (2)
l --- (3)
o --- (4)
d --- (0)
a --- (1)
t --- (2)
a --- (3)
w --- (4)
o --- (5)
r --- (6)
d --- (7)
```